# Upgrade Ruby on Rails in default cpanel ( 1.8.7 to 2.4.0)

Tags: ruby, cpanel, whm

I have success install ruby on cpanel but it run on 1.8.7 how i can upgrade into 2.4.0 in this case i have root access. I have try to follow https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-use-cpanel-ruby-on-rails-area-with-ruby-2-and-rails-4.433192/
but not success.

Comment: What exactly did you try? What exactly didn't work? Was there some kind of error message? Btw. what version of Rails to run?

Comment: if i use 1.8.7 ruby on my cpanel, i can use this for deploy my apps.. 
but it is too old..